# Use `see=` key and new command `\acro` in preamble

Tags: glossaries

I have the code below. For some reason I cannot use the definition of `\acro` to define new acronyms in the preamble.

I can use it within `\begin{document}` `\end{document}`. However, also in that case I am not able to properly display the acronym entry and the `see=TV` key.

How can I use the `\acro` definition in the preamble and print the TV definition with the `see=TV`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[nomain,acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newcommand*{\acro}[3][]{\newacronym[#1]{#2}{#2}{#3}}

\acro{TV}{Television}
\acro{TVWS}[see=TV]{Television White Spaces}
\newacronym[see=TV]{TVB}{TVB}{Television Broadcast}


\begin{document}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=list]

\ac{TVWS}\\
\ac{TVB}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The optional argument is the first one, not the second one!

Comment: Any news on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The O.P. defined

```
\newcommand*{\acro}[3][]{\newacronym[#1]{#2}{#2}{#3}}
```

but tries to call it (why???)

```
\acro{TVWS}[see=TV]{Television White Spaces}
```

i.e. the optional argument is at the 2nd place here. This is difficult to achieve with a standard `\newcommand` approach, but easy with `\NewDocumentCommand` from `xparse` package:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\acro}{mom}{%
  \IfValueTF{#2}{% Is there an optional 2nd arg?
    \newacronym[#2]{#1}{#1}{#3}%  Yes, there is!
  }{%
    \newacronym{#1}{#1}{#3}% Nope, there isn't!
  }%
}
```

Here is the example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[nomain,acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries}

%\newcommand*{\acro}[3][]{\newacronym[#1]{#2}{#2}{#3}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\acro}{mom}{%
  \IfValueTF{#2}{%
    \newacronym[#2]{#1}{#1}{#3}%
  }{%
    \newacronym{#1}{#1}{#3}%
  }%
}
\makeglossaries

\acro{TV}{Television}
\acro{TVWS}[see=TV]{Television White Spaces}
\newacronym[see=TV]{TVB}{TVB}{Television Broadcast}


\begin{document}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=list]

\ac{TVWS}

\ac{TVB}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works for the definition of `\acro` command. But the definition of `TV` entry does not appear in `\printacronyms`. I do not know if I misunderstood the `glossaries` documentation. But for me, if I use `see=` it should be printed, even if it is not used in the document itself.

Comment: @cacamailg: I'll check

Comment: @cacamailg: See page 70 of the current version manual of `glossaries-user`: The cross-referenced entry (i.e. TV here) will not be added automatically -- unless I did misunderstand the documentation

Comment: Let's see if the author of the package may help us on that. Let's wait a little, otherwise I will accept your answer.

Comment: @cacamailg: Nicola will frown on your `\acro` macro anyway :-P

Comment: It is just a shortcut. He will not be mad on me :P.

Comment: @cacamailg: She ;-) :D

Comment: Ups! Sorry for that :(